# Elasticsearch curl query: List of indices having 0 documents

Tags: curl, elasticsearch, indices, documents

I am trying to get a list of all of my Elasticsearch indices that have 0 documents.

My approach was to query `_cat/indices`

```
curl -GET 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices' -d '{
    "query": { "match": { "docs.count": "0" } }
}'
```

But it does not seem to work as I see indices with more than 0 documents being listed.

`Cat indices` documentation can be found here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/cat-indices.html

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you `grep` for the result instead?

Comment: In fact what I am trying to do is to later remove these indices from my cluster (the ones that have 0 documents). The only characteristic they have in common is their matching number of documents. Would I be able to `grep` on `docs.count` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel awk and cat API would be a better choice. You can use the below command to get what you are looking for -

```
curl -GET 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices' 2>/dev/null | awk ' ($6 == 0) {print $3}'
```

Comment: Thank you, this works well! Would there be a way to easily delete the returned elements with this method?

Comment: I believe as of now , we don't have any other methods.

Comment: I tried to apply `-XDELETE` to your command in various ways but could not get it working :( Any ideas?

Comment: What were you trying with DELETE

Comment: The position of the document field is 7 now. Here is a sample from the official documentation:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-indices.html#cat-indices-api-example so it should be
`curl -GET 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices' 2>/dev/null | awk ' ($7 == 0) {print $3}'`

Answer (score 0):

use this bash script
|tee to output.txt if you want

eg

```
sh list.sh | tee output.sh
```

uncomment `xdelete` if you want to delete it

```
#!/bin/bash

# Elasticsearch URL
ES_URL="http://localhost:9200"

api_timeout=5m


# Get a list of all indices
indices=$(curl -s "${ES_URL}/_cat/indices" | awk '{print $3}')

# Loop through each index and check if it has zero documents
for index in $indices; do
  doc_count=$(curl -s "${ES_URL}/${index}/_count" | jq -r '.count')
  if [ "$doc_count" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "${index}"
    # curl -X DELETE "${ES_URL}/${index}?master_timeout=${api_timeout}"
  fi
done
```